# How to get version using EWS powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

```
$Service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1);
```

In the above line Exchange2013_SP1 is hardcoded. Using powershell how can I dynamically get the version when running the script?

Comment: Have you tried typing:
`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::` in the PS ISE and seeing what options are available via Intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

In the Code provided, you are trying to create an instance of WebServices.Data.ExchangeService(something similar to [this](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/GregTate/archive/2015/03/18/using-exchange-web-services-managed-api-in-powershell.aspx)), specifying exchange version via [ExchangeVersion Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeversion).
However - the query after that is about knowing how to obtain Exchange Version via PowerShell. Probably this is very well documented and googling shows many hits about checking Exchange Version:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2012/04/27/powershell-determine-version-number-build-number-and-service-pack-of-exchange-server/

https://blog.jasonsherry.net/2012/12/27/get-exchangever/

Answer (score 0):

If you make a request like Binding to the Inbox of a Mailbox in the response the build details of the CAS Server the processed the response is returned https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.serverinfo(v=exchg.80).aspx and exposed via the ExchangeService Class this can be used to tell the CU that's been applied to the Target and is the most useful thing if you trying to track errors etc.

EWS Schema version (which is what you have hardcoded) and Server versions are two different things so I would suggest you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn741586(v=exchg.150).aspx . Autodiscover can be used to find the highest EWS Schema version of CAS server.